# Advanced Typescript inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am currently trying to build a plugin library. These plugins have some methods in common, and others that are really different.

Example :

```
class PluginA extends Plugin {
  specificAMethod() {
    ....
  }
}

class PluginB extends Plugin {
  specificBMethod() {
    ....
  }
}
```

What I want to do, is have a plugin registry that goes something like this :

```
const pluginRegistry: Record<string, Plugin> = {
 a: PluginA,
 b: PluginB
}
```

The problem with this, is that if I try to do `a.specificAMethod()` I will get the error `method specificAMethod does not exist on type Plugin`.

And since this is a lib, I want it to be automatic, so that when the users imports a Plugin, it automatically has the right type instead of doing `(a as PluginA).specificAMethod()`.

I also tried union types instead of inheritance, but same problem.

I also know that I can get away with it with just doing :

```
const pluginRegistry = {
  a: PluginA,
  b: PluginB
}
```

But I don't like it since it works when exposing the library but I actually want to have a type that I can reuse because I need it for other abstract cases and it is also more interesting this way.

Is there a way that I can get TypeScript to correctly infer the type of each plugin automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also know that i can get away with it with just doing :
>
> ```
> const pluginRegistry = {
>     a: PluginA,
>     b: PluginB
> }
>
> But i don't like it since it works when exposing the library but i actually want to have a type that i can reuse because i need it for other abstract cases...
> ```

That's not a problem, just get the type from the object:

```typescript
const pluginRegistry = {
    a: PluginA,
    b: PluginB
} as const;
export type PluginRegistry = typeof pluginRegistry;
//          ^? −−−− type is { readonly a: typeof PluginA, readonly b: typeof PluginB };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKIFcDmBLAdtA3tAvgWAChDRIZ5l0BBaAUwA8AXGtAEzMVQ00Ol+ggAONYCgBmKYJQCyNBgAsA9iwAUASiw8+WgPTboAOkP7NvfATPFwUOB3QAhWo2ZsbFLif5CR44HZnylNQ0CLR09I2MQvjMLAmAFNAgGaAFbNAAlGlQkgCcAT2gAXmCtMAAuV05KABoPACMK8k47WvNoSGh4xIYAbkJ6AQUc5IY8oUr0TOyGfKLoUaEFURS0qZRcvL6CXVDQgD0AfkIdgBUxmmh1rGgcmjAWBJAC8vnzpYm0Gpu7h7Qn6Aar0Wyya9lwPSAA)

> ...and it is also more interesting this way

If you don't want to do that, you'll have to write your type with explicit keys and types for them:

```typescript
export type PluginRegistry = {
    // `readonly` is optional, depends on your use case
    readonly a: typeof PluginA;
    readonly b: typeof PluginB;
};

const pluginRegistry: PluginRegistry = {
    a: PluginA,
    b: PluginB,
};
```

...since `Record<string, Plugin>` will be quite broad.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKIFcDmBLAdtA3tAvgWAChDRIZ5l0BBaAUwA8AXGtAEzMVQ00Ol+ggAONYCgBmKYJQCyNBgAsA9iwAUASiw8+WgPTboAOkP7NvfATPFwUOB3QAhWo2ZsbFLif5CR44HZnylNQ0CLR09I2MQvjMLAnoBBQAnBmgGAE8hV04AJRpUCAZEtOgAXmCw6AADRJowFgU0EDTK6BQYBQEGFAawEAAaaBYaIVZ2jDSFBEToBAgaaGBIGg8auoam6DAALlSMmgVRLKoAbhXa+sbigCMd9KEDo7Q7U-MX4gaC6AFbNFz8wrSO3IOTybQBpXKfG2j0ofQ8N0edjhr0IQA)